# cannot use emacs in kde konsole - Output has been suspended by pressing Ctrl+S. Please press Ctrl+Q to resume

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde, emacs

I am trying out the kde terminal app, konsole, on my ubuntu gnome machine, and I think it is great, in general.  However, when I ssh to another machine, and open a file in emacs, searching the document with ctrl-s fails with the message "Output has been suspended by pressing Ctrl+S. Please press Ctrl+Q to resume."  And then all I can do is exit, after pressing Ctrl-Q.  I have already tried entering in my .bashrc:

```
stty -ixon;
stty -ixoff;
```

It changes nothing.

In other terminals on the same remote machine, Ctrl-S works fine in emacs.  And on my own machine, emacs is fully functional, including search.

What can I do?  Without the ability to use emacs remotely, I will have to abandon konsole and all of its nice features.

I have spent some time searching for an answer...  Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 8):

Sorry, just minutes after posting this, I found the answer here:

https://github.com/ivanov/vim-ipython/issues/8

to quote Vladimiroff from the post:

```
"in Konsole you can disable this feature, by going to
Settings -> Configure Profile -> Choose current profile -> Edit Profile -> 
Advanced Tab
and disable 'Enable flow control using Ctrl+S and Ctrl+Q'"
```

I did this, and I can confirm that emacs with Ctrl S now works on the remote machine (in its profile).

Comment: Thanks! I found the setting under Settings -> Edit Current Profile -> Advanced -> Flow control, in Konsole 21.12.1. There is no longer any mention of Ctrl+S and Ctrl+Q in newer versions. Further, there doesn't appear to be any option I could see to change these  shortcuts in the Configure Keyboard Shortcuts menu.